# How to disable button click if value inputed is less than Minimum bid amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to be able to disable button click if the value entered in the text box below named "bidamt" is less then the Minimum Bid value below in the table. How do I go about doing this? I am trying to do this in JavaScript but it doesnt seem to pull the Minimum Bid value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      @model IList<NucorPrototypes_V1.ViewModel.AuctionPage>

      @{
          ViewBag.Title = "MyBids";

       }

      <!doctype html>
       <html>
       <head>
<title>Auction </title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkBids(el) {
        var bidInput = el.value
        var MinBid = confirmbids.MinBid.value
        if (el.value <= MinBid) {
            document.getElementById("Bid").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("Bid").disabled = false;
        }
    }


    function RemoveBid(rb) {
        if (typeof (rb) == "object") {
            $(rb).closest("tr").remove();
        }

    }


</script>
 @*<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#bidamt').bind('keyup', function () {
       if (Filled()) $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
   });

   function Filled() {
       var filled = true;
       $('body input').each(function () {
           if ($(this).val() == '0') filled = false;
       });
       return filled;
   }

       *@
      @*<script type="text/javascript">

       //Validates that textbox value entered is a number or a number with a decimal
       function checkDec(el) {
           var typedBid = el.value
           var min = confirmbids.MinBid.value

           if (el.value <= confirmbids.MinBid.value) {
               //alert("Invalid Bid Amount. Please enter a correct bid amount.");
               document.getElementByName("Bid").disabled = true;
           }
           else {
               document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'Your Bid is ' + el.value;
               document.getElementByName("Bid").disabled = false;
           }
       }
```

*@

```
      <body>
        <div id="header" style="background-color: #008751">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0; color: #FFFFFF">Secondary Coil Auction</h1>
      </div>
         <br />

          <div id="content">

    <center>
    <h4>In order to confirm bid you must enter a Bid Amount or Remove Bid before clicking Confirm.</h4>

   @*Table that populates with bids the user selects. Here they can place a bid and           remove a bid.*@


<form method="post" id="confirmbids" action="PlaceBid">
    <table id="myTable1" border="2" style="background-color: #B0B0B0" cellpadding="10" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Bid Amount per 100 Weight</th>
            <th>Remove Bid</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Minimum Bid</th>
            <th>Current High Bid</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Heat Number</th>
            <th>Gauge</th>
            <th>Width</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Defect 1</th>
            <th>Defect 2</th>
            <th>Defect 3</th>
        </tr>



        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" @*pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01"*@ name="bidamt" onkeyup="checkDec(this);" id="bidamt"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Bid" id="removeme" onclick="RemoveBid(this);"/>
                </td>                    
                <td>
                    <input type="text" style="background-color: #B0B0B0" readonly="true" name="coilID" value="@item.Coil_ID" />                  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" style="background-color: #B0B0B0" readonly="true" name="MinBid" value="@item.Auc_MinBid" />  
                    @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Auc_MinBid)*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HighBid)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Grade)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_HeatNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Gauge)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Width)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Weight, new { @id = "CoilWeight" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Defect1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Defect2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coil_Defect3)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    <center><input type="submit" name="Bid" id="Bid" onclick="checkBids(this)" value="Confirm Bids" />
    </form>
    <br />
    </center>
</div>
<center>

<div class="well">
    <div id="message"></div>     
</div>


</center>
<br />
<br />
```

`

Comment: It doesnt necessarily have to disable the button. I just need it to not submit the actual amount entered in the input field and give them an error and let them re enter amount.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can try this:
To use jquery you just embed

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

on the head tag of your html file. And put this on your click event.

```
$("#Bid").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

like this:

```
$("#Bid").click(function(){
      if(something true){
       $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Would I put this in my JavaScript function? Also, Would this need to be done on button click or on keypress? Thanks again

Comment: For some reason it is not wanting to pull in my Minimum Bid in the Function. I need it to be if(bidamt <= MinBid){ alert("Invalid Bid") and also disable button click }

Answer (score 0):

You put your bidamt textbox in foreach loop and you set id="bidamt". So the problem is you can not set the same id many element, id is unique. The second problem is you called checkBids function on click event of button, so you can not get value of the button.